La restricción de la política de la organización “iam.disableServiceAccountKeyCreation” se aplicó
La restricción de la política de la organización “iam.disableServiceAccountKeyCreation” se aplicó en tu organización.
No puedo crear ni descargar una clave JSON para realizar una migracion de mail a office 365
tanto el grupo como el proyecto tienen la funcion de propietarios y adicionalmente "Administrador de clave de cuenta de servicio"
Intento habilitarlo manualmente con el procedimiento:
gcloud iam service-accounts keys enable KEY_ID 
--iam-account=SA_NAME@PROYECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com
--project=PROYECT_ID
Pero la consola responde:
NOT_FOUND: Service account key **** does not exist
No se que mas hacer he creado y eliminado en varias oportunidades el proyecto. Realizo el mismo procedimiento en otra cuenta sin problemas.
Quedo atento a sus comentarios.

tengo el mismo problema ahora no se si alguien ha podido saber como ?¡

lograron resolverlo?
